# KVO observer crash on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, key-value-observing

I’ve a app in App Store which was working fine on iOS 10. But recently I’m getting many crash reports and all logs points to KVO crash and all are happening on iOS 11, below is the crash log.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e7a858 object_isClass + 16
1  Foundation                     0x1836d72bc KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED + 68
2  Foundation                     0x1836d5ad0 NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 300
3  QuartzCore                     0x186e35024 -[CALayer setDelegate:] + 108
4  UIKit                          0x18c866698 -[UIView dealloc] + 708
5  UIKit                          0x18c93f08c -[UILabel dealloc] + 192
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
7  UIKit                          0x18c86678c -[UIView dealloc] + 952
8  CoreFoundation                 0x182b911b4 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 140
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
10 UIKit                          0x18c86678c -[UIView dealloc] + 952
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
12 UIKit                          0x18c86678c -[UIView dealloc] + 952
13 libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
14 UIKit                          0x18c86678c -[UIView dealloc] + 952
15 UIKit                          0x18cbd3248 -[UINavigationTransitionView dealloc] + 96
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
17 UIKit                          0x18c86678c -[UIView dealloc] + 952
18 UIKit                          0x18cbd319c -[UILayoutContainerView dealloc] + 60
19 libobjc.A.dylib                0x181e9a13c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
20 CoreFoundation                 0x182b88aac _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
21 UIKit                          0x18cc705fc _prepareForCAFlush + 132
22 UIKit                          0x18cb555b8 _afterCACommitHandler + 236
23 CoreFoundation                 0x182c6a910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
24 CoreFoundation                 0x182c68238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
25 CoreFoundation                 0x182c68884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
26 CoreFoundation                 0x182b88da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
27 GraphicsServices               0x184b6b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
28 UIKit                          0x18cb6978c UIApplicationMain + 236
29 MyApp                      0x1009bf748 main (main.m:14)
30 libdyld.dylib                  0x182619fc0 start + 4
```

The crashes has crossed over 200 crashes and all are same logs. I’ve not been able to reproduce this crash and kind of stuck on how to proceed next. My entire project is written in objective-C and when I checked there is only one method where I’m using a KVO. Below is a model of my method on how I’ve used it.

```
-(void)loadData
{
 //Some code
if (myAlerts) {
        [myAlerts removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@“liveAlerts"];
    }
    myAlerts = myModel.alerts;
    [myAlerts addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"liveAlerts" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:NULL];
}

To remove I use the cleanup method in other viewcontrollers when I no longer need it


-(void)cleanup
{

//Some code

[myAlerts removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"liveAlerts"];
 myAlerts = nil;

}
```

All the other observers which I've added in my project are NSNotificationCenter observers, could that cause this type of crash log?

Comment: Do you call `cleanup` or remove observer in `dealloc` method of your class? If not, maybe it's the problem.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this crash from iOS 11 and 12.
I'm using FBKVOController which should manage unobserve automatically...

Comment: I have the same crash. Were you able to figure out a reason why this was happening ?